# How do you GET the id using mysqli_stmt_fetch()

Tags: php, mysqli, fetch

im new in mysqli prepared and i convert all my mysqli to mysqli prepared.

i want to get the id of the specific data and i can easily do that in mysqli. here is my old code:

```
        echo "<th>".$record['first_name']."</th>";
        echo "<th>".$record['middle_name']."</th>";
        echo "<th>".$record['last_name']."</th>";
        echo "<th>".$record['date_added']."</th>";
        echo "<th>".$record['crew_status']."</th>";
        echo "<th><a target='_blank' href='review.php?id={$record['id']}'>Click</a></th>";
        echo '</tr>';
```

and in the mysqli prepared, this is my code:

```
        while($record = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>".sprintf("%s", $col2)."</th>";
        echo "<th>".sprintf("%s", $col3)."</th>";
        echo "<th>".sprintf("%s", $col4)."</th>";
        echo "<th>".sprintf("%s", $col18)."</th>";
        echo "<th>".sprintf("%s", $col19)."</th>";
        echo "<th><a target='_blank' href='review.php?id=$rows[] = $col1'>Click</a></th>";
        echo '</tr>';
```

below is my entire code:

```
    $search = 'PENDING';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `crew_info` WHERE `crew_status` = ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $search);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $col1, $col2, $col3, $col4, $col5, $col6, $col7, $col8, $col9, $col10, $col11, $col12, $col213, $col14, $col15, $col16, $col17, $col18, $col19);

echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>All Crew</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="POST">
        <table border="2" align="center" width="600" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="4">
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Middle Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Date Added</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>REVIEW</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>';
            $rows = array();
            while($record = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>".sprintf("%s", $col2)."</th>";
            echo "<th>".sprintf("%s", $col3)."</th>";
            echo "<th>".sprintf("%s", $col4)."</th>";
            echo "<th>".sprintf("%s", $col18)."</th>";
            echo "<th>".sprintf("%s", $col19)."</th>";
            echo "<th><a target='_blank' href='review.php?id=$rows[] = $col1'>Click</a></th>";
            echo '</tr>';
          }
         echo '</table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>';
```

Comment: if what used to work in mysql_ (if that's what you used to use before) but doesn't in mysqli_, then you must've done something wrong. What you posted for code isn't enough and the method you're using to connect with. Otherwise, check for errors. Till then, *night night.*

Comment: Show us more of your code. Ideally the query and any code used to generate/execute/display it.

Comment: i added my entire code guys. thank you

Comment: You're just printing things out - there's nothing different about printing the ID out. Can't you just use `$col1` instead of `$rows[] = $col1`?

Comment: so now we've got code. One thing to know about binding results, is that the total number of binded variables you're using MUST match the total number of columns you have in your db when doing `SELECT *`. So, again.. check for errors.

Comment: @Fred-ii- everything is fine. nothing to worry about the codes. my only problem is fetching the id of the specific id. but it's okay now. i solved my problem thanks

Comment: thank you guys i already solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead using

```
$rows[] = $col1
```

why don you change it to $col1 only? remove the $rows[]

change your code from:

```
    echo "<th><a target='_blank' href='review.php?id=$rows[] = $col1'>Click</a></th>";
```

to this

```
    echo "<th><a target='_blank' href='review.php?id=$col1'>Click</a></th>";
```